# Counting number of inversions

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to build divide and conquer algorithm, that counts a number of inversions. Here is my code, which is based on merge-sort:

```
def merge_sort(array):
    if len(array)<=1:
        return array

    mid = len(array)//2

    left_array = merge_sort(array[:mid])
    right_array = merge_sort(array[mid:])
    res = merge(left_array,right_array)

    return res


def merge(left_array, right_array): 
    global inversions
    inversions = 0
    result = []
    i = j = 0


    while i < len(left_array) and j < len(right_array):
        if left_array[i] <= right_array[j]:
            result.append(left_array[i])
            i+=1


        else:
            result.append(right_array[j])
            inversions += len(left_array[i:])
            print(right_array[j],left_array[i])
            j +=1


    result.extend(left_array[i:])
    result.extend(right_array[j:])
    return result


test = [5 ,2 ,10 ,8 ,1 ,9 ,4 ,3 ,6 ,7]

#test = [1,3,5,2,4,6]

merge_sort(test)
inversions
```

In my case I got 11, but should be 22.

For example we have an array [1,3,5,2,4,6]. By divide and conquer approach(merge-sort) we divide this array on two parts. In the first step we select element 1 as the smallest one, insert it in the new array and delete from the left array. In the second step the smallest element is 2(right array). Here we see, that in the left array there are 2 elements. It means, that we have 2 inversions, in which element 2 is involved. 
The main idea is, that the number of inversions = the number of the elements, that are lefr in the left array, if we pick an element from the right one.

I have tried to implement this logic in code, but it doesn't work properly. Can you help me to find my mistake?

Comment: Can you add the input and expected result? Why the code doesn't work?

Comment: @iGian added. I don't know why my code doesn't work, that's why i am asking:)

Comment: Move `inversions = 0` outside of the `def merge(left_array, right_array):`, just before `merge_sort(test)`

Comment: @iGian Thank you, it works! Can you explain me please why it didn't work in my code?

Comment: It's because each time you call `merge()`, `inversions` gets reinitialized to `0`. Fpr debug, add some `print(inversions)` and run the code as original and after the change. You'll see for yourself.